# Como um gatilho pode ser interrompido?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Utilizando ORACLE SQL Developer, tenho um gatilho que, ao tentar atualizar dados numa tabela, ele verifica se satisfaz as condições e, satisfazendo ou não as condições, devo registrar essa atividade em uma tabela de log. Entretanto, se ele não satisfazer a condição devo bloquear a operação de atualização.

O que tentei:

- `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'...');`

Tentei usar uma exceção que eu dou um `RAISE` onde não satisfaz a condição, e chamo o application erro acima, porém, apesar de realmente finalizar a operação, perco todos os meus dados de log, de modo que a tentativa mal sucedida de atualizar não foi registrada.

Existe alguma forma de apenas dar um break no gatilho, interromper ou algo assim sem perder meus registros de log?

Para mostrar o código eu reduzi o problema. Suponham que tenho uma tabela `PUBLICATIONS` que apenas guarda informações de uma publicação:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLICATIONS (
IDPUBLICATION NUMBER;
JOURNALNAME VARCHAR2(100);
TYPEPUB VARCHAR2(50);
);
```

E meu gatilho é:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GATILHO_ATT_PUBLICATIONS
BEFORE UPDATE ON PUBLICATIONS
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
-- variável para log
V_ID_REG LOG_TABELA.ID_REG%TYPE;

V_BLOCK_ATT EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
SELECT MAX(ID_REG) INTO V_ID_REG FROM LOG_TABELA;   -- id do log anterior, que será incrementado

-- Incrementa o id do log
IF (V_ID_REG IS NULL) 
    THEN V_ID_REG := 0;
ELSE  V_ID_REG := V_ID_REG + 1;
END IF;

-- se tento atualizar alguém além de typepub, levanto exceção.
IF  :NEW.IDPUBLICATION != :OLD.IDPUBLICATION OR 
    :NEW.JOURNALNAME != :OLD.JOURNALNAME OR 
    INSERT INTO LOG_TABELA
    VALUES (V_ID_REG,SYSDATE,'Atualização cancelada');
    RAISE V_BLOCK_ATT;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO LOG_TABELA
    VALUES (V_ID_REG,SYSDATE,'Atualização realizada');
END IF;

    -- Não bloqueia a operação 
    EXCEPTION WHEN V_BLOCK_ATT THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Atualização cancelada');

-- Bloqueia a operação, mas não executa o log
--   EXCEPTION WHEN V_BLOCK_DEL THEN end;
-- RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Atualização interrompida!');

END;
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Creio que isto caducou , mas onde fica o commit/roolback , na função que fez o insert ? Tentou com SAVEPOINT ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10001.htm   https://luis-alexandre.com.br/controle-de-transacoes-banco-dados-oracle/

Comment: Olá, a solução é utilizar autonomus transactions, de modo que quando o raise application erro for invocado ele não vai cancelar o log pois são transações autônomas. Estou de férias no momento, mas vou colocar um código de exemplo aqui assim que possível e fechar essa pergunta.

Comment: Sempre vale , é um problema recorrente, pode ajudar outrem, boas férias !